# Does your lost health transfer to your new form while wild shaping?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

In the middle of a battle, whilst I'm wild shaped into a brown bear, I take 20 damage and drop to 14hp. I then wildshape into a dire wolf form. Does the damage carry over to my wolf form, or am I at full health again in wolf form?

It's very confusing to my players and me since it doesnt say in the PHB.